# ViewPager retaing old Fragments on screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using `ViewPager` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to show fragment. Initially there are 2 fragments added Fragment1 and Fragment2 and 3rd fragment Fragment3 is added at 2nd position after recieiving response from server. So after all pages are added this should be sequence of Fragments in ViewPager --> Fragment1, Fragment3, Fragment2.

The Problem is after Fragment1 and Fragment3 are added and app is making server call before adding 3rd Fragment at 2nd position if I do screen rotation multiple time then after 3rd fragment is added it still shows old copy of Fragment2 which was at 2nd position initially at 2nd position and 3rd position have new copy of Fragment2. So Fragment3 doest shows up in ViewPager. Sequence after adding 3rd Fragment -- > Fragment1, old copy of Fragment2, New Fragment2.

I am overriding `onSaveInstanceState` and calling `super.onSaveInstanceState` in my Activity.

Also I have tried returning `POSITION_NONE` from `getItemPosition`. I read somewhere that ViewPager save copies of fragment. Also through debugging I checked that ViewPager contained 2 copies of Fragment2 when issue was reproduced even though `getItem` of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` returned different Fragments for each position but still at 2nd position it was showing old fragment. For testing purpose in `getItem` I returned Fragment1 for all positions so that all 3 pages should be same but even after that in 2nd position it was showing old copy of Fragment2 when I reproduced issue with steps mentioned above.

So how to clear `ViewPager` so that it does not save old fragments. How to refresh ViewPager so that it does not retain old copy with fragments. I think problem is with onSaveInstanceState but I need it. How can I exclude `ViewPager` when views are saved in `onSaveInstanceState`. I have tried `mViewPager.setSaveEnabled(false)` but it takes too much memory.

I found that the problem is `instantiateItem` method of adapter does not call getItem due to which old fragment is returned.

**Below is solution code**

**Code:**

```
 @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Object obj = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            Fragment fragment = mFragments.get(position);

            if((obj!=null && fragment!=null) && !(obj.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(fragment.clss.getSimpleName()))){
                destroyItem(container, position, obj);
                return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            }else{
                return obj;
            }
        }
```

Comment: have you checked [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9646622/1396082)

Comment: You removed your comment..Did it work for you now?

Comment: The problem is instantiateItem method of adapter does not call getItem due to which old fragment is returned. I am finding a way to make it call getItem.

Comment: read top response in link below , paying attention to 'OVERLAPPING VIEW' that is mention. You will have to do explicit remove on the added view.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529499/problems-with-android-fragment-back-stack/14295368#14295368

Comment: Actually this answer is recommended way to accomplish fragment retaining: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29288093/1732338

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, I am posting my solution here. I override `instantiateItem` of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and inside it I am getting object from `super.instantiateItem` and comparing its classname with classname of object at that position from list of fragments that I am maintaining.

If classname is not same its mean `super.instantiateItem` returns duplicate fragment. So I am calling `destroyItem` at that position and again calling `super.instantiateItem` and returning it from `instantiateItem`.

`FragmentStatePagerAdapter` return old fragment because in framework code arraylist `mFragments` has duplicate fragment and it just return fragment at current position. I think it should compare fragment at the position in list with currently displaying fragment before returning it.

Comment: can you show me some (dummy) code please? I do no understand your solution with just words (sorry, not good in English).

Comment: @Poutrathor Sorry for late reply. I have added code in answer.

Comment: @k2ibegin Code is there in question statement above.

Comment: @anujprashar sorry, I don't understand what you mean, either. Can you provide a sample app that demonstrates this or a code block which shows what you've done?

Answer (score 1):

Only override this method in FragmentpagerAdapter

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object);
}
```

then remove `super.destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object);`
from your code