# Fragment not being replaced correctly

Tags: android, android-fragments

I created an activity with a navigation drawer and a FrameLayout. This frame layout should contain the fragment which corresponds the selected navigation item. So I followed the instructions in android tutorials, but it doesn't work.

Problem: 
It seems to me the fragments are only added and not replaced. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

My activity xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainViewDrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainViewContentFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/drawer_content_padding" >
 </FrameLayout>


 <ListView android:id="@+id/mainViewDrawerList"
     android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_size"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     android:choiceMode="none"
     android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
     android:dividerHeight="0dp"
     android:background="@color/drawer_background"
     />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

my first fragment xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:id="@id/fragmentProfile">

    <TextView
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/mainViewProfileGivenNameLabel"
            />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profileGivenNameTextView"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />
</LinearLayout>
```

my second fragment xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@id/fragmentProtocol">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/protocolTableListView"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
              android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
              android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

my transition method in the activity:

```
private void switchToFragment(int navigationId, boolean addToBackStack){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    String fragmentTag = null;
    boolean fragmentCreated = false;
    switch(navigationId) {
        case NavigationItemProvider.NAVIGATIONITEM_PROFILE:
            fragmentTag = NAVIGATIONTAG_PROFILE;
            break;
        case NavigationItemProvider.NAVIGATIONITEM_PROTOCOL:
            fragmentTag = NAVIGATIONTAG_PROTOCOL;
            break;
    }

    // determine if the fragment is already instanciated otherwise create
    FragmentBase fragment = (FragmentBase)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
    if (fragment == null){
        if (fragmentTag == NAVIGATIONTAG_PROFILE) {
            fragment = new ProfileFragment();
            fragmentCreated = true;
        }
        else if(fragmentTag == NAVIGATIONTAG_PROTOCOL)    {
            fragment = new ProtocolFragment();
            fragmentCreated = true;
        }
    }

    // switch to fragment
    if (fragment.isVisible()){
        return;
    }

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if (fragmentCreated)         {
        transaction.replace(R.id.mainViewContentFrame, fragment, fragmentTag);
    }
    else{
        transaction.show(fragment);
    }

    if(addToBackStack)
    {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: transitions are complicated.. read it carefully      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529499/problems-with-android-fragment-back-stack/14295368#14295368

Comment: solved the problem:
In onCreate I returned the result of super.onCreate and not the result of Layoutinfalter.inflate and in addition I didn't call inflate with last parameter set to false.

Answer (score 1):

solved the problem: 
In onCreate I returned the result of super.onCreate and not the result of Layoutinfalter.inflate and in addition I didn't call inflate with last parameter set to false.