# Android onkeydown() not working

Tags: android, onkeydown

I have an activity where I flag full-screen once the orientation changes, problem is when you are currently in full-screen and you press the back button it will go back to the previous fragment in full-screen, which I do not want. I added this code but it doesn't seem to be called:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
    //do what ever you want here
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    getActivity().getActionBar().show();
    getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "backbuttonpressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    getActivity().finish();
    return true;
  }
  return super.getActivity().onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Try adding the code on `onBackPressed`.

Comment: are you calling this from fragment??

Comment: onBackPressed doesnt work either

Comment: yes sir, I am calling this from a fragment activity

Comment: after back pressed need to go to previous fragment?

Comment: no, after back is pressed, I want to change the orientation of the screen, remove fullscreen, and go back to previous fragment... all in a single press

Comment: is your code really executed? do you see the toast?

Comment: @Schnizel1337, no it is not executed.

Comment: so your general problem is that onBackPressed isn't calles, right?

Comment: @Schnizel1337, yes sir.

Comment: @JanManaloto refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529499/problems-with-android-fragment-back-stack

Comment: @JanManaloto try writing the `onKeyDown` code you've written in your `activity` not in the `fragment` (`return true` in the `activity` so `onKeyDown` should not dispatch it any further to your `fragment`)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Setting s = Utils.readSettings(this);
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```