# Android Maintaining own collection of fragments and resume the fragment if it exists

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have few fragments  attached to one activity.I want to retreive the fragment from the stack if your exsists in the collection/stack.And i do not want to pop out or loose the fragment once it loaded.I want to reuse the same fragment all time when needed.

1. Is there any way i can use fragment manager and achieve this ?

or

2. can i maintain my own hashMap of fragments and implement it ?

Using 2 way, i tried doing it,i am getting exception.

I'm trying to use fragmemt.getView() and   attached the view to the frameLayout and the exception is thrown as shown :

```
layout.addView(fragment.getView());

09-29 09:16:24.887    3481-3481/com.sample.android.app W/System.err:   
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call     
removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Note:  I cannot pop fragment as i ll loose the fragment.I just want to reuse the same fragment all time to avoid loading data.

Comment: `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(theTag)` if != null then use it, if == null then create new one ? then use pair FragmentTransaction show/hide instead remove

Comment: As per the link,if i found the fragment by tag ,i should replace it.http://stackoverflow.com/a/14295368/1140321.Doing this i have to load the data again.I want to get the quickness when we pop the fragment from backstag without loosing the fragment.

Comment: no, you should hide current and show founded one ...

Comment: Aren't you basically just looking for `FragmentPagerAdapter` with `ViewPager`?

Comment: @421 are you using a view pager?

Comment: Yes..i am using view pager