# Back press fragments issue in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have four Fragments: A, B, C, D. Now I am moving from A --> B so my code will be

from **A to B**

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new B())
    .addToBackStack("A")
    .commit();
```

Now from **B to C** so code will be

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new C())
    .addToBackStack("B")
    .commit();
```

Now from **C to D**. But I don't want to include C in backstack because on back press I don't want C fragment to be shown.

```
 getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
     .beginTransaction()
     .replace(R.id.content_frame, new D())
     .commit();
```

Now when I press Back button it will work perfectly upto A. Now if I repeat same process again. Now again on back press From D Fragment, I will be sent directly on A fragment instead of B fragment. Can you please figure it out the mistake that I am doing in above code?

Comment: @HareshChhelana That is not the problem the question shows not calling the add to back stack. The issue is the way fragment transactions work. Read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529499/problems-with-android-fragment-back-stack

Comment: @Zach.. Actually i didnt get from that link

Comment: Yeah it doesn't define a clear answer just gives an overview of how it works. I've had similar troubles and basically had to define my own backstackchangelistener that defines what happens on back stack calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code of BackStackChangedListener.

```
public  static void performNoBackStackTransaction( final FragmentManager fragmentManager, String tag, Fragment fragment) {
    final int newBackStackLength = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() +1;

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag)
            .addToBackStack(tag)
            .commit();

    fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            int nowCount = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
            if (newBackStackLength != nowCount) {
                // we don't really care if going back or forward. we already performed the logic here.
                fragmentManager.removeOnBackStackChangedListener(this);

                if ( newBackStackLength > nowCount ) { // user pressed back
                    fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide same String value for addToBackStack for single Stack.

```
.replace(R.id.content_frame, new B())
.addToBackStack("stack") 

.replace(R.id.content_frame, new C())
.addToBackStack("stack")
```