# Fragment Resume state issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

Before some days I have posted one question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33797908/3974236)

It is working perfectly, but i have added another **fragment E**. Now the problem is that i want to move from **Fragment D** to **Fragment E** but i want fragment D in its pause state. So i have done following code

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, departingCheckOutFragment).addToBackStack(TAG).commit();
```

It is working perfectly when i press back button. I am able to go to **Fragment D** in its resume state and createview is not called. But now when i press again back previous transaction is called **Fragment C** to **Fragment D** which i don't want to open. I directly want to go to **Fragment B** Can you please help me out with this issue?

Thank You

Comment: If i understand you correctly.. You have Fragment B -> Fragment C -> Fragment D -> Fragment E transactions. And you want fragment C not appear in backstack? If yes, just do not add it to backstack in fragment B

Comment: @aelimill have already done that. But i want fragment D to be in its pause state so i Used above code to go from D to E

Comment: Well, I think you should override onBackPressed() in Activity and make the the its logic working for you requirements

Comment: @aelimill how? Its already working Just i have issue in going back from fragment D