# fragments back navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, back-stack, android-navigation

I explain the scenario below:

Activity1(fragment1) -> Activity1(fragment2) -> Activity1(fragment3) -> Activity2(fragment4)(OK-button)

if i click on OK button on fragment4 in Activity 2, i should land onto Activity1(fragment2) and upon clicking on back button on fragment 2, it should land onto fragment1.

I tried the following code:

```
activity?.supportFragmentManager?.popBackStack()
```

But it doesn't work. Any help or suggestion on how to resolve this issue. You may ask why i'm using lots of fragments here but i really don't have any other options.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Also Have a look at [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12529499/3559908)

Comment: @Vall0n thanks for the response. but as per the link, all the fragments are in one acitvity. but in my case, fragment1,2,3 in one activity and fragment4 is in different activity.

Comment: Did you try to `activity?.supportFragmentManager?popBackStackImmediate()`?

Comment: popBackStack() is not working in multiple activity!

Answer (score 0):

When you click on `OK` button in `Activity2(fragment4)`, just put an entry in `sharedPreference` before calling `Activity1` intent like this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString(key, "1");
editor.commit();
```

then call your `Activity1`:

```
Intent Activity1 = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity1.class);
startActivity(Activity1);
```

Now in your `Activity1`, before setting the contentview, just check the shared preference if it have a variable `key` with value `1` stored in it. If it contains a value `1`, then load fragment2 in the frame layout `frm`. Like this:

```
sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if (sharedPreferences.contains(city)) {
       FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
       fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frm,new fragment2()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

When this activity is called normally, shared preference will not have the value `1` in `key`, so fragment1 will be loaded as your normal flow.

Now, when you move to next fragment from here, just store `0` in `key` variable in shared preference. This can be done in `onDetach()` method of the `fragment2`

Also to go back to fragment1, you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46425415/8165315) answer for more detailed solution.